# Restating a theorem within \hyperlink produces extra vertical space above

Tags: hyperref, thmtools

When I restate a theorem, it behaves as normal. But when I restate it as the second option of \hyperlink, an extra line appears above. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

Some text
 
\hypertarget{minq:genre}{
    \begin{restatable}{theorem}{Question}
        Why did the chicken cross the road?
    \end{restatable}
    }

Some text 

\Question*

Some text

\hyperlink{minq:genre}{\Question*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were lucky that it works at all. With pdflatex and lualatex your example gives a fatal error as you start and end a link in vertical mode.

Basically it doesn't work: start and end of links can affect spacing when used in the wrong place. You could put the restated theorem in a box, but then the second line would look odd. So I would advice to use an explicit text, if you want a link back to the original. There is no need to use a `\hypertarget`, the theorem already has an anchor that you can retrieve with a `\label`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}
\declaretheorem{theorem}
\begin{document}

Some text
 

\begin{restatable}{theorem}{Question}\label{minq:genre}
   Why did the chicken cross the road?\\ To get on the other side
\end{restatable}

Some text 

\Question*

We restate Theorem \ref{minq:genre} from page \pageref{minq:genre}:

\hyperref[minq:genre]{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent}\Question*\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The \hypertarget seems to be necessary. When I point \hyperlink to the theorem's \label, the restated theorem gets formatted as a link but does not do anything when I click on it.

Comment: Either way, the minipage with \dimexpr does get rid of the space above, which is what I needed. Thanks!